# Ng2-translate and webpack

Tags: android, ios, internationalization, nativescript, ng2-translate

Good afternoon guys, I'm using ng2-translate to do the translation of the app and run perfectly with the command: tns run ios | Android
        But I'm having an error while running with webpack with the following parameters: tns run ios --bundle --env.uglify --env.aot

```
    Error:
    CONSOLE LOG file:///app/vendor.js:1:1200993:
    CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/vendor.js:1:28276: ERROR TypeError: this.http.get(this.prefix+"/"+e+this.suffix).map is not a function. (In 'this.http.get(this.prefix+"/"+e+this.suffix).map(function(e){return e.json()})', 'this.http.get(this.prefix+"/"+e+this.suffix).map' is undefined)
    CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/vendor.js:1:1125775: bootstrap: ERROR BOOTSTRAPPING ANGULAR
    CONSOLE ERROR file:///app/vendor.js:1:1125775: bootstrap: this.http.get(this.prefix+"/"+e+this.suffix).map is not a function. (In 'this.http.get(this.prefix+"/"+e+this.suffix).map(function(e){return e.json()})', 'this.http.get(this.prefix+"/"+e+this.suffix).map' is undefined)
    getTranslation@file:///app/vendor.js:1:886381
    getTranslation@file:///app/vendor.js:1:887491
    retrieveTranslations@file:///app/vendor.js:1:887380
    setDefaultLang@file:///app/vendor.js:1:886824
    n@file:///app/bundle.js:1:88782
    ka@file:///app/vendor.js:1:110925
```

Repository to test: https://github.com/gustavost26/teste-ng2-translate

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52872622/ng2-translate-incompatible-with-webpack

Answer (score 0):

Good that you provided a example project, I was able to quickly review it and looks like you are using latest version of Angular and rxjs but your translate module is completely outdated.

Replace it with the refactored latest version of same package

```
npm install --save @ngx-translate/core @ngx-translate/http-loader
```

Updated **app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from 'nativescript-angular/forms';
import { NativeScriptHttpClientModule } from 'nativescript-angular/http-client';
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app.routing";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";

import { ItemService } from "./pages/item/item.service";
import { ItemsComponent } from "./pages/item/items.component";
import { ItemDetailComponent } from "./pages/item/item-detail.component";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

export function HttpLoaderFactory(httpClient: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(httpClient, '/assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule,
        NativeScriptHttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        ItemsComponent,
        ItemDetailComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        ItemService
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
/*
Pass your application module to the bootstrapModule function located in main.ts to start your app
*/
export class AppModule { }
```

Updated **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import * as Platform from "platform";

@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
        this.translate.setDefaultLang('en'); //chage pt
        //this.translate.use(Platform.device.language.split('-')[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I created this new repository configured with ngx-translate but it does not work: https://github.com/gustavost26/teste-ngx-translate